# SwiftUI conditional view will not animate/transition

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, transition, swiftui

I’m trying to get my views to animate/transition using `.transition()` on views. I use similar code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514133/how-do-i-transition-from-a-login-view-to-a-tabview-in-swiftui) and put `.transition()` to both conditional views.

```
struct Base: View {
    @State private var isSignedIn = false

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if(isSignedIn){
                Home().transition(.slide)
            }else{
                AuthSignin(isSignedIn: self.$isSignedIn).transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AuthSignin: View {
    @Binding var isSignedIn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isSignedIn = true
            }) {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .bold()
                    .frame(minWidth: CGFloat(0), maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(CGFloat(10))
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

However, whenever I click on the "Sign In" button (with or without `.transition()`), the app will freeze for a second and then the `Home()` view will suddenly appear without any animation/transition. I've also tried to wrap `self.isSignedIn = true` in `withAnimation` but it still won't work. Any ideas or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Place your `.transition` on the **container of the views that will switch**, not each conditional view. Here's a trivial example from some code I have done (which works).

In the main View that needs to transition conditionally:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppWrapperView: View {

  @State var showFirstRun:Bool = true

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if (showFirstRun) {
        FirstRunView(showFirstRun: $showFirstRun)
      } else {
        Text("Some other view")
      }
    }
    .transition(.slide)
  }
}
```

Then, somewhere in the view that triggers the change in condition:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstRunView: View {

  @Binding var showFirstRun:Bool

  var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
      withAnimation {
        self.showFirstRun = false
      }
    }) {
      Text("Done")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( Im trying to mimic Google Maps app and there when you press on search field presents overlay view with fade (opacity) transition. So it's only working when transition applied to "second" view and only to present (dismissing without animation) but doesn't work at all when it's applied to ZStack.

Comment: The working solution was about to add zIndex to at least "Second" view which you want to present or probably even better to add it to all ZStack views. Seems to be a bug. Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730074/transition-animation-not-working-in-swiftui

Answer (score 18):

I had to put my `if..else` statement inside `ZStack` container instead of `Group`. Seems that `Group` was the main reason for broken animation in my case. Also, I applied `.transition` in combination with `.animation` to container instead of views.

```
ZStack {
  if(isSignedIn){
    Home()
  } else {
    AuthSignin(isSignedIn: self.$isSignedIn)
  }
}
.transition(.slide)
.animation(.easeInOut)
```

Comment: `ZStack` instead of `Group` did the trick - thanks.

Comment: Replacing `Group` with `ZStack` solved my issue as well! Thanks for the tip! ‍♂️

Comment: You have to watch out for the .zIndex(). If more than 1 view is placed into a ZStack, it can happen that the animation will only play on appearing, but not on the disappearing. The reason for this is the position of the view in the ZStack. When a view is dismissed, it is placed behind all other views in the ZStack. 
To Avoid problems with animations of any kind, set the .zIndex of every view in the ZStack. Also avoid using 0 for the index.

Comment: As of Jul 22, 2023, Group is working for me instead of ZStack

Answer (score -2):

Put 
WithAnimation before self.isSignedIn = true

Comment: Yea I’ve tried it like I mentioned where I wrap `self.isSignedIn = true` in `withAnimation` but still. Now the problem seems to be like there would be a freeze for 2 seconds whenever a new complex view that was not displayed (for example Home()) is loaded. Hence no animation.

Comment: then you should show us your complex home view. there must be the problem.